# Is there a way to import the extensions and download them from extensions.json in vscode?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to import the extensions and download them from extensions.json in VS Code?

I can import the settings.json and keybindings.json because I can find them as JSON but is there a way to do so with extensions.json?

Comment: the extensions installed are sub folders of a folder named `extensions` in the `user/.vscode` folder, some extensions have platform dependent parts, you can add a required extensions part to the workspace

Answer (score 0):

[extensions.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_workspace-recommended-extensions) is a workspace-specific feature. That should already be working for you: when you open up such a workspace, VS Code should prompt you whether you want to install the recommended workspace extensions, and/or show those extensions in the Extensions View.

If you're talking about non-workspace extensions, then you can use the [Profiles feature of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles) ([new in version 1.75](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75#_profiles)), which allows you to specify extensions that are part of a profile.